# CKEditor control not working in IIS 7 intergrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webforms, ckeditor

ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms

Works fine in classic mode, but then my URL-routing doesnt work.

Basiclly, I think the page isnt loading up the javascript for the editor. All other js elements works fine. Everything works fine on localhost.

Anyone who had the same problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Its because im using the CKeditor .NET-control, which was build on the (now) old CKEditor. The newly released CKEditor is working with Intergrated mode.

The only problem with that is without the control (just the javascript) its pure client side, thus you have to handle the whole validation issue (validateRequest=false thing thing)

Answer (score 0):

I have ckeditor working fine in webforms/IIS7 in integrated pipeline. It's .net 3.5, but I'm sure that's not the issue. It's probably a pathing problem.

Perhaps try a tool like fiddler or firebug's net tab to see if there are any errors with the resources being pulled into the editor.

Comment: Yeah, I looked through the code with firebug, and the paths seems to be good. It loads the javascript fine.